# GlyuckDataGrid API has no support for Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

Currently, I'm migrating an app from Swift 3 to Swift 4, but it has using **GlyuckDataGrid API** and now there's has not support to Swift 4,I have seen the author's [GitHub](https://github.com/glyuck/GlyuckDataGrid) profile that he has not committed changes since November 2016.

Does anyone know any alternative available for Swift 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided not to use this API anymore. Because I found an alternative for Data Tables compatible with Swift 4, which is [SwiftDataTables](https://github.com/pavankataria/SwiftDataTables).
It seems that it works.

Comment: Thank you for using SwiftDataTables @xorez. If there's anything you'd like to see improved please let me know so I can incorporate those features.